# BigTextStyle notifications not expanding from FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-notifications

I wrote the below method for showing FCM notification on my android 5.1 device. When I run the code inside a FirebaseMessagingService it is just giving single line notification , where if I run the same code inside my Activity its giving expandable notifications.

I basically need my long FCM text notifications to get expanded on notifications rather than showing partial notification text.

Any leads?

```
private void showNotif(String messageBody){

     Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
     intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

     // Constructs the Builder object.
     NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
         .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
         .setContentText(messageBody)
         .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL) // requires VIBRATE permission
         .setAutoCancel(true)
         .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
         /*
          * Sets the big view "big text" style and supplies the
          * text (the user's reminder message) that will be displayed
          * in the detail area of the expanded notification.
          * These calls are ignored by the support library for
          * pre-4.1 devices.
          */
         .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
         .bigText(messageBody));

     // android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat mNotifManager = (NotificationManagerCompat) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
     mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
 }
```

Comment: are you triggering your FirebaseMessagingService when your app is on the background?

Comment: yes. I tried it on both cases. Same result.

Comment: Silly question, but is it definitely at the top of the notification drawer in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

This should work . 
Big Text notifcations are shown in normal mode when there are other notifications on top . Try to expand it while testing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to creare notification using this method https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send and not using firebase console and all would be ok

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.